# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '__h' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-dom, preact

I am getting this error, While using these aliases. Can you help me? Thanks!

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '__h' of null
    at hooks.module.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at x (hooks.module.js:1)
(anonymous) @   hooks.module.js:1
x   @   hooks.module.js:1
```

> "preact": "^10.5.12"

Webpack alias code!

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      "react": "preact/compat",
      "react-dom": "preact/compat"
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show code. Your alias is obviously fine, as it's pointing to Preact.

Comment: It's a simple react app nothing fancy and I am using web-dev-server for hot reloading.

Comment: Okay, but that's not any code. The `TypeError` indicates you have a problem in your code, it has nothing to do with the alias. Can't help you until you provide something.

Comment: It is a huge project. First things were fine but then after, it started showing this error. I don't know the cause, also tried looking for this error, but ain't found anything useful.

Comment: it turns out that adding useEffect hook fires this error.

Comment: You might be loading `preact` in your bundle twice. You need to make sure it's loaded only once. Again, need some code though.

Comment: seems like it only happens inside `<Suspense>` component